# python: accessing a list using a dictionary

Tags: python

i read a csv into a variable called `b`

now i am going through every row in it like this:

```
for row in b:
```

this dictionary gives me the positions of where these drugs are in the `row`:

```
  generic_drugs_mapping={'MORPHINE':[86],
                        'OXYCODONE':[87],
                        'OXYMORPHONE':[99],
                        'METHADONE':[82],
                        'BUPRENORPHINE':[28],
                        'HYDROMORPHONE':[54],
                        'CODEINE':[37],
                        'HYDROCODONE':[55]}
```

i am setting `drug = 'MORPHINE'`

am i able to do this:

```
row[generic_drugs_mapping[drug][0]]!=''
```

to check whether there is a value in the `row[86]!=''` ??

Comment: First, don't wrap all the numbers into lists. `'MORPHINE:86'` is better.

Comment: Second, couldn't you have *tried* it before asking whether it would work?

Comment: Third, you've done the same thing here as you did in a previous question by reading the CSV file into a variable first. It is more efficient and less memory-intensive to read the file in chunks; this work is handled for you by the `csvfile.Reader` or `csvfile.DictReader` classes in the `csvfile` module.

Comment: thank you very much, if it is 'MORPHINE:86', then how would i access it?

Comment: In your case, `generic_drugs_mapping[ "MORPHINE" ] == [ 86 ]`. Instead, it would be `generic_drugs_mapping[ "MORPHINE" ] == 86`. So you could get rid of the `[0]` lookup.

Comment: thank you very much that does indeed make it simpler

Comment: katrie, can you please help me make this more efficient instead of reading this entire 100mb file into a variable, to do as you said, but i cannot follow you

Comment: @I__: If you don't want a variable referencing 100mb of data, read/parse one/few line(s) at a time, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work, assuming those are 0-based indexes into `row`.  Is there a reason the elements of the dictionary are lists?